# QGIS MSSQL Feature table Repeated error

Tags: qgis, sql-server, features

I have a MSSQL (2008 R2) SQL view that is visible and displayable within QGIS (LTR ESSEN 2.14.15) itself. However if I attempt to style the results by classification the map display disappears. If I add any form of querying to the table it disappears.

Loading the Feature table for review [image: MSSQL 2008 R2 view]
shows the inherent issue- all the fields are returning an error within QGIS.

The view behaves perfectly within SQL Management Studio and within QGIS itself[image: MSSQL 2008 R2 View rendering]
as you can see above, it is up to a point. So I'm discounting //most// connection issues.

But I can't apply any styling or additional queries to the table whilst it is returning a table full of Errors.

Sadly this doesn't appear to be specific to this one particular view, but any view I'm pushing through to QGIS.

Has anyone ever encountered this type of behaviour before? And any concept of how to fix?

Comment: please share a screen capture of where you're getting the features to disappear...

Comment: looks like qgis is have trouble reading the table attributes. is there a unique key or a duplicate id in there?

Comment: @DPSSpatial- it's like the one with dots but without them!

Comment: @Mapperz- it's a view so there is no primary Key but there are also no complete duplicates. It's patently able to _read_ the table at some point as when styling is in simple mode (ie the default when first loading a point layer) it _will_ render the points but when you attempt to load the feature table or apply any form of query or classification of point display it all goes <sad face>

Comment: @DPSSpatial- sorry re-read your comment- it's the whole layer that fails to render- it's not datum shift or location specific it's all 105k features